# Foreign Key "can not add or update a child row"

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

First off I am using both LibreBase and phpmyadmin

In short I have 2 tables a Student and a StudentFeedback table

```
Student contains:
StudentUserID(primary key) type=int(11) Null=no  Default=none Extra=Auto_Increment

FirstName type=varchar(50) Null=Yes Default=Null

Surname type=varchar(50) Null=Yes Default=Null

StudentFeedback contains:

FeedbackID(primary key) type=int(11) Null=no  Default=none Extra=Auto_Increment

Student(I think is foreign key) type=int(11) Null=Yes Default=Null

Feedback type=varchar(150) Null=no  Default=none
```

Now what I want to happen is a student can be created using a form on librebase which is then added to the table e.g.

```
1 Joe Bloggs, 2 Bill Gates, 3 Steve Jobs.
```

However I have created another form to then add data to the feedback table so that Joe Bloggs or indeed Bill or Steve can use this form enter there user id and then add there feedback. This data will then be displayed by a variety of queries and reports which I am confident I can do. The problem arises when I try to add data via the librebase form. 
The form to add a new student consists of:

```
Firstname (textbook)
Surname (textbox)
```

The data will however not enter/be input in to the table as librebase throws up an error box saying

> ```
> Error inserting the new record
> SQL Status: 23000
> Error code: 1452
>
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails >(`mydb`.`student`, CONSTRAINT `student_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`StudentUserID`) >REFERENCES `StudentFeedback` (`Student`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE >CASCADE)
> ```

The same error appears if I try to add data into the form I have created to add feedback to the StudentFeedback table

Apologies if this makes next to no sense I'll happily answer any questions you may have.

Comment: Please provide your insert query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem now, I had a constraint blocking the input or certain data and so used an sql query to view all my database constraints and then used another query to remove the relevant constraint. After that it's as simple as adding the foreign key ensuring that I used on update cascade on delete cascade

Answer (score 0):

While Creating foreign key you have to give referencing properties:
  **ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE CASCADE**

please go through the referencing properties.

Comment: I have wrote two pieces of sql code to try that Akash and neither seem to be working:

    ALTER TABLE StudentFeedback,
    DROP PRIMARY KEY,
    DROP FOREIGN KEY,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (FeedbackID),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Student) REFERENCES Student(StudentUserID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE     CASCADE

Or my second piece 

    ALTER TABLE StudentFeedback (
    INDEX par_ind (Student),
    FOREIGN KEY (Student) 
        REFERENCES Student(Student_StudentUserID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)

But neither seem to be working both throwing up errors